# Issue converting .DER certificate files

Tags: conversion, certificate, openssl

I have a .der files (certs) and when trying to convert using:

```
openssl x509 -in v1_ff.der -inform der -text -noout
```

or

```
openssl x509 -in v1_ff.der -inform DER -out mycert.pem
```

or

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in v1_ff.der -out converted.pem
```

or

```
openssl x509 -in v1_ff.der -inform der -outform pem -out cert.pem
```

I am receiving this error:

```
unable to load certificate
140199928912640:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1197:
140199928912640:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:374:Type=X509_CINF
140199928912640:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:697:Field=cert_info, Type=X509
```

Doesn't seem it has more info available over the internet. Any one know why?
File:[v1_ff.der](https://expirebox.com/download/fa11121bb03b872195dc2c06f8c0049d.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is a PKCS#7 SignedData file which has been used to transport certificates.

```
openssl pkcs7 -in v1_ff.der -inform der -print_certs -out multi_cert.pem
```

You'll then probably need to explode the `multi_cert.pem` to one cert per file, depending on what the system or application you're sending it to expects.

Comment: You were right.. It worked! Thanks @bartonjs